# Append the lists in a DataFrame Column: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which has a column of lists and i'm filling this lists with new values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3],'col2':[4,5,6], 'col3':[[],['x','y','z'],['x1','y1','z1']]}, index=['a','b','c'])

print(df)  
           col1  col2          col3
        a     1     4            []
        b     2     5     [x, y, z]
        c     3     6  [x1, y1, z1]
```

Here, the 'col3' column has lists, and what I'm trying to do is replace the current value with itself + the new list and using `set()` just to drop duplicates if exists. The new list is not always the same, I just did this way to make it easy. Observe that the order of the loop is not the same of the indexes, even though I need to put the right value in the right place.

```
n=0
for index in ['b','a','c']:
    n+=1
    list_to_append = ['x'+n,'y'+n,'z'+n]
    new_list = list(set(df.loc[index,'col3']+list_to_append))

    df.loc[index,'col3'] = new_list
```

This is what I expect to get:

```
print(df)  
           col1  col2                          col3
        a     1     4              ['x2','y2','z2']
        b     2     5      [x, y, z,'x1','y1','z1']
        c     3     6   [x1, y1, z1,'x3','y3','z3']
```

out:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

is there any correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)

> Use `at` if you only need to get or set a single value in a DataFrame or
> Series

so in the assignement line you simply have to use `at` instead of `loc`

```
df.at[index,'col3'] = new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help. `apply` might not be the best approach depending on the size of `df`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3],'col2':[4,5,6], 'col3':[[],['x','y','z'],['x1','y1','z1']]}, index=['a','b','c'])

df['col3'] = df['col3'].apply(lambda x: list(set( x + ['x3','y3','z3'])))

print(df)

   col1  col2                      col3
a     1     4              [y3, z3, x3]
b     2     5     [x, y3, z3, z, x3, y]
c     3     6  [z1, y3, z3, y1, x1, x3]
```

Comment: This would help, but this new list is not always the same. It's variable depending on the index

Comment: i missed that. sorry. :(

Comment: @Lucas you should reflect this by editing your question with a proper example

Comment: okay, I just did. Sorry

Comment: @Lucas check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use `apply` with help of a `set` difference:

```
S = set(list_to_append)
df['col3'] = df['col3'].apply(lambda x: x+list(S.difference(x)))
```

output (with a new column for clarity):

```
   col1  col2          col3                      col4
a     1     4            []              [z3, y3, x3]
b     2     5     [x, y, z]     [x, y, z, z3, y3, x3]
c     3     6  [x1, y1, z1]  [x1, y1, z1, z3, y3, x3]
```

For a variable input use a Series:

```
s = pd.Series([list((f'x{n}',f'y{n}',f'z{n}')) for n in range(len(df))],
              index=['b','a','c'])


df['col4'] = (df['col3']+s).apply(lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(x)))
```

output:

```
   col1  col2          col3                      col4
a     1     4            []              [x1, y1, z1]
b     2     5     [x, y, z]     [x, y, z, x0, y0, z0]
c     3     6  [x1, y1, z1]  [x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2]
```